# Understanding aws-sdk-net for Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, aws-sdk-net

I am trying to understand the aws-sdk-net for Unity package and I don´t understand how to proceed with the rest of the tutorial.

What do I do with the information for the .xml file? I am trying to setup aws-cognito but the aws setup page is very confusing.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforunity/developerguide/setup-unity.html

Thank for the help

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a link.xml file and place it in your Resource folder. And awsconfig.xml is optional. Also AWS SDK for Unity was last updated 5 years ago, you should consider using .net SDK.

Comment: Ok, thanks! You mean this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/latest/developer-guide/welcome.html, thanks for confirming!